# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate the limit  $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n)}\,?$$

I tried to search it in the forum but I didn't find, this limit is pretty famous and I know it is equal to 1, but I not sure I understand the technique there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  l'Hôpital's rule, one can prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)} = 1$$then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n)}=1 \cdot 1=1$$

Comment: You don't need _L'Hôspital's rule_ at all.

Answer (score 2):

Using the *Squeeze theorem*:
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n+1)}\leqslant\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln n}\leqslant&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(2n)}{n\ln n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\frac{\ln 2n}{\ln n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(\frac{\ln 2}{\ln n}+1\right)\end{aligned}$$

---

There is another *L'Hôspital -free* approach in evaluation of

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln (n)}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}-1\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}{\ln(n)}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\ln(n)}\right)\end{aligned}$$
So, our initial expression becomes:
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\ln(n)}\right)=1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$a_n:=\dfrac{n+1}{n}$;

$\lim_{n}a_n=1$;

$b_n:= \dfrac{\log (n+1)}{\log n}$;

$\dfrac{\log (n+1)-\log n}{1}=\dfrac{1}{s}$ where $s \in  (n,n+1);$ (MVT)

$b_n-1= \dfrac{\log (n+1)}{\log n}-1=$

$\left (\dfrac{1}{s} \right) \dfrac{1}{\log n};$

Hence $\lim_{n} {b_n}=1$;

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(n+1) = \ln(n)+\ln(1+1/n)
\lt \ln(n)+1/n$
since
$\ln(1+1/n)
=\int_0^{1/n} dt/(1+t)
\lt \int_0^{1/n} dt
=1/n$.

The quotient is thus less than
$\dfrac{(n+1)(\ln(n)+1/n)}{n\ln(n)}
=(1+1/n)(1+1/(n\ln(n)))
\lt (1+1/n)^2
$.